# How I can execute the second query in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I use this code it run very good but the problem how I can execute the second query:

```
$query .= "SELECT * FROM `course` where id = 201102887;";
```

which is from another table.The first query work fine . Can you help me or  advise me to another way to run many query  .

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "uoh");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM `student_record` where id = 201102887;";
$query .= "SELECT * FROM `course` where id = 201102887;"; 

/* execute multi query */
if (mysqli_multi_query($link, $query)) {
    do {
        /* store first result set */
        if ($result = mysqli_store_result($link)) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
                printf("%s\n", $row[0]);
                printf("%s\n", $row[1]);

            }
            mysqli_free_result($result);
        }

        /* print divider */
        if (mysqli_more_results($link)) {
            printf("-----------------\n");
        }
    } while (mysqli_next_result($link));
}


/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Run the queries as individual queries, one after the other

Comment: You could use UNION to join the two queries.

Comment: Or you could just join the two tables with an INNER join.

Comment: what do you mean by Run the queries as individual queries, one after the other Mr.Mark Baker

Comment: I mean exactly what I said..... run the first query using `mysqli_query()`, fetch the result from that, then run the second query using `mysqli_query()`, and fetch the result from that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try UNION for this

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "uoh");
$query = "SELECT * FROM `student_record` where id = 201102887 UNION SELECT * FROM `course` where id = 201102887";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{
    print_r($row);
}
?>
```

This should print two arrays (one per row), one from the `student_record` table (assuming `id` is unique) and one from the `course` table assuming that `id` is unique.